# Javascript: (ES5) Definitive guide to array iteration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

There is so much confusion about how to "correctly" iterate over an Array in Javascript. There are at least two posts with several hundred upvotes, but the answers are very contradicting. I'm confused.

ES5 added the `Array.prototype.forEach` function. Is this the final answer or are there still pitfalls to avoid stepping in?

Please post the true one iteration if there is one at all. I am okay with using ES5 Don't post if you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: "the true one iteration" is just `for(;;)`, simple and fast.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: If you want to avoid unpleasant surprises, there is no way around understanding Javascript's Object model, including prototypical inheritance. Javascript Arrays are basically Objects with a few additional properties, and they are *very* unlike Arrays in any other popular language.

`Array.prototype.forEach` and also `jquery.each` have a much bigger pitfall than just the clean `for (var k in a)` which is often advised against. I haven't seen this pitfall mentioned in any other post.

Look:

```
Array.prototype[2] = 'hi';

var a = [];
a.forEach(alert); // nothing
alert(a);  // ''

a[3] = 3;
a.forEach(alert); // 'hi', then '3'
alert(a);  // ',,hi,1'
```

What's happening here? See the [spec-compliant algorithm on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (under "Compatibility") implementing `Array.prototype.forEach`.

`a.forEach(myCallback)` is more or less equivalent to the often-seen

```
for (var p = 0, len = a.length; p < len; p++) {
    if (p in a)
        myCallback(a[p], p, a);
}
```

This means it loops over properties in the prototype chain just as well! But only in a less reliable way, because it only loops over properties fulfilling `p < len`.

### 100% reliable methods:

The versions below only iterate over enumerable properties. The `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` function can be used instead of `Object.keys` to include non-enumerable properties.

**numeric, own, sequential**

```
a.forEach(function(v, k, a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty[k])
        myCallback(v, k, a);
});
```

**own, sequential**

```
Object.keys(a).sort(mySortFunc).forEach(function(k) {
    myCallback(a[k], k, a);
});
```

**numeric, sequential**

```
alert("Don't do it");
```

**own**

```
Object.keys(a).forEach(function(k) {
    myCallback(a[k], k, a);
});
```

**(no constraints)**

```
for (var k in a) {
    myCallback(a[k], k, a);
}
```

I don't consider the last one such a bad option. It's a very honest and concise way to iterate. As a side-note, sequential numerical iteration has proved to have a performance advantage on most implementations at least for non-sparse arrays; but maybe it's not the spec's fault.

Comment: `Array.prototype[2] = 'hi';` is such an odd edge case that it hardly seems to be a reason for avoiding the perfectly good `Array.prototype.forEach` function. If you're going to be worried about that, you'd have to also avoid `some`, `every`, `map`, `filter`, etc. etc. To look at it a different way, if I'm going to add an element to the prototype that way, then I probably **want** `forEach` to iterate over it.

Comment: @torazaburo: You didn't get my point. What you say ("... then I probably want to iterate over it") is exactly why I don't get what's so wrong about `for (x in y)`. Both iteration types (including or not including prototypical properties) have their valid uses. But the "iterate over any numeric prototypical property only if we have own properties greater than that" behaviour of `forEach` probably has no uses, and I consider it an unreliable misfeature that isn't documented anywhere (and maybe wasn't considered in the spec)

Comment: Yes it is quirky with numeric keys in general. My previous comment was not accurately phrased, I'm removing it.